# Warning: PDO::exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in(...)

Tags: php, pdo, parameter-passing, prepared-statement

```
if (isset($_POST["add_employee"]))
{
    $result = false;

    global $con; 

    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Address, ZipCode, City)
                VALUE($full_name, $address, $zip_code, $city)');

    $stmt->bindParam($full_name, $_POST['full name']);
    $stmt->bindParam($address, $_POST['address']);
    $stmt->bindParam($zip_code, $_POST['zip_code']);
    $stmt->bindParam($city, $_POST['city']);

    $result = $con->exec($stmt);
```

Hello guys,

I've been working on a project myself for a while. Now I am stucking on it. I know there are similar questions about it, but I also read them without a success.
In this case, I always got a warning output which is linked to the line 26.
I search through many forums to get an answer, why it is not working and what kind of parameter should be given in exec(?)? Obviously, exec($stmt) doesnt work and it must be a string.

Some of you said that the exe() should be replaced by execute(), but it didnt work. Instead there is an output like "Call to undefined method PDO::execute()" (if i use $con->... instead of $stmt->...)

I would appreciate it, if you can help me and give a short explanation.

Thanks and have a nice day:)

Comment: images of code doesn't do anyone any good, especially yourself.

Comment: yeah you are right. I deleted it and just post a  fragment of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute the statement, not the connection ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)). So you would instead do this:

```
$stmt->bindParam($full_name, $_POST['full name']);
$stmt->bindParam($address, $_POST['address']);
$stmt->bindParam($zip_code, $_POST['zip_code']);
$stmt->bindParam($city, $_POST['city']);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

[PDO::exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) is for non-prepared queries, such as

```
$con->exec("DELETE FROM fruit WHERE colour = 'red'");
```

Also, your query will not work the way you think, as the placeholders will not expand. If your placeholders are in the variables (such as `$full_name = ':full_name'`), then you need to use double quotes:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Address, ZipCode, City)
            VALUE($full_name, $address, $zip_code, $city)");
```

Otherwise, you'll need to actual placeholders, like this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Address, ZipCode, City)
            VALUE(:full_name, :address, :zip_code, :city)');
$stmt->bindParam(':full_name', $_POST['full name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
$stmt->bindParam(':zip_code', $_POST['zip_code']);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city']);
```

Comment: you need to fix their query also

Comment: Hmm. There is that.

Comment: I'm afraid so. I think they might not know how.

Comment: Hm...I guess i will keep working on it and try it out. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help and contribution.

Comment: Hey man, I could solved the problem. Firstly, your point with "execute()" was right and i get it now. Second, I added in all "bindParam", as a third parameter, PDO::PARAM (e.g. PDO::PARAM_STR). Furthermore, I created  a "try/catch - block" and put the codefragment into it and wrote in the catch-phrases: PDOExeception $result {...}

Answer (score 0):

Here, the appropriate solution:

```
if (isset($_POST["add_employee"]))
{   
    try {

        $result = false;
        global $con;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Address, ZipCode, City) VALUE(:full_name, :address, :zip_code, :city)";

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':full_name', $_POST["full name"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST["address"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':zip_code', $_POST["zip_code"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST["city"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result = $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $result) { 
        if ($result === false ) {
            echo "Error adding new employee!<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "New employee sucessfully inserted!<br>";
        }
    }   
}
```